# How to fix Compile Error: Sub or function not defined in VBA?

Tags: vba

This is a code that goes through the cells in column B in [sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zo9aF.png). If it finds a value that is not a date in column B, then it copies it, pastes it another sheet called 'errors' and then deletes that row from Sheet2. Whenever I try to run this, however, I get a 'Compile Error: Sub or function not defined'. I saw some other posts on this, but nothing mentioned there seemed to work for me.

```
Sub removeerrors()
Dim i As Range
Dim x As Double
x = Worksheet("Errors").CountA("A1:A100")

    For Each i In Worksheet("Sheet2").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        If IsDate(i.Offset(0, 1)) = False Then
            Range(i, i.End(xlToRight)).Copy
            Worksheet("Errors").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0).Paste
            Range(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change `Worksheet` to `Worksheets` with 's' at the end.

```
Sub removeerrors()
Dim i As Range
Dim x As Double
x = Worksheets("Errors").CountA("A1:A100")

    For Each i In Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
        If IsDate(i.Offset(0, 1)) = False Then
            Range(i, i.End(xlToRight)).Copy
            Worksheets("Errors").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0).Paste
            Range(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few other errors/changes that could be made within the script

1. Add `s` to Worksheet
2. Use `Option Explicit` at top of code
3. `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA`
4. Add range as argument to `Counta` i.e.  `Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Errors").Range("A1:A100"))`
5. Ensure correct ranges being worked with by wrapping in  `With Worksheets("Sheet2")`
6. Determine last row by coming up from bottom of sheet with `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`, or you could end up looping to bottom of sheet
7. Correct syntax for delete line:   `i.EntireRow.Delete`
8. You can put copy paste on one line:  `.Range(i, i.End(xlToRight)).Copy Worksheets("Errors").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0)`
9. Be wary of using `End(xlToRight)` in cases of potentially ending up at far right of sheet.
10. Optimize code by switching some things off e.g. prevent repaint by switching off screen-updating during looping
11. Gather ranges to delete with Union and delete in 1 go or loop backwards to delete

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub removeerrors()
    Dim i As Range, x As Double, loopRange As Range, lastRow As Long, unionRng As Range
    x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Errors").Range("A1:A100"))
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set loopRange = .Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
        If lastRow = 1 Then Exit Sub
        For Each i In loopRange
            If Not IsDate(i.Offset(0, 1)) Then
                .Range(i, i.End(xlToRight)).Copy Worksheets("Errors").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0)
                If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then
                    Set unionRng = Union(unionRng, i)
                Else
                    Set unionRng = i
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    If Not unionRng Is Nothing Then unionRng.EntireRow.Delete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

use fully qualified range references

loop backwards when deleting rows

update target sheet pasting row index

as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeerrors()
    Dim iRow As Long
    Dim x As Double
    x = Worksheets("Errors").CountA("A1:A100")

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") ' referecne "Sheet2" sheet
        With .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("A2").End(xlDown))  ' reference referenced sheet range from cell A2 down to next not empty one
            For iRow = .Rows.Count To 1 Step -1 ' loop reference range backwards from its last row up
                If Not IsDate(.Cells(iRow, 2)) Then ' if referenced range cell in column B current row is not a date
                    .Range(.Cells(iRow, 1), .Cells(iRow, 1).End(xlToRight)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Errors").Range("A1").Offset(x, 0) ' copy referenced range current row spanning from column A to next not empty column and paste it to sheet "Errors" column A row x
                    x = x + 1 ' update offset
                    .Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete ' delete referenced range current row
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```